# Route issue when Deploying angular 6 on aws ec2 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I have created mean stack application and uploaded it on AWS Ec2 server using ubuntu 16.04.
Now when I visit my link 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4200' it works fine and opens 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4200/login'. But when I try to reload or type 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4200/userhome' or 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4200/login' then it gives me 404 error.
Also, log out is not working after login.
All the project is working fine when I use 'ng serve'
I have read this: https://angular.io/guide/deployment. I have created the '.htaccess' file in my folder but still the same issue.

I have read many solutions on StackOverflow but none seems to work for me. I think I am missing or not doing some steps correctly. 
I am unable to set this .htaccess.

See below .htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

I have added following code in apache.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

See the app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { UserhomeComponent } from './userhome/userhome.component';
import { DriverComponent } from './driver/driver.component';

const routes:Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'login',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'register',component:RegisterComponent},
  {path:'userhome',component:UserhomeComponent},
  {path:'driver',component:DriverComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am using 'http ://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4200/' as my url
The project is placed in 'var/www/html'

PLEASE HELP ME IN THIS REGARD!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to configure that every thing that not file or nor directory, will be redirect to the main index.html file ... and then the angular route will do the rest

if you using apache so add .htaccess file and those lines,

if you using nginx so you need to login via SSH to the server and update the nginx conig

in path :  /etc/ngins/sites-enabled/{THE_CONFIG_FILE}

don't forget to restart the nginx service

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L,R]
```

Comment: I have added .htaccess file but my project is not in 'var/www' which is the default root folder for apache. My project is in home/ubuntu/project_name/dist/frontend. How do I change the default directory for apache/Nginx so that it could work? I am stuck at this point.
Thanks for responding

Comment: you using apache or nginx?

Comment: Apache. 
Also notice I am using port 4200 e.g: 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:4200'

Comment: Why are you using port 4200 on production? You don't need it... you run the build as abgular wrote in their tutorial?

Comment: I am using two ports 
4200 for the angular project and 8080 for express and node
Is this the right method?
This is the first time I am deploying. I am not getting any good guide to understand this well. Can you refer some guide or source to deploy the project with ports and no routing issues?

Comment: those ports not relevant in this case, you are in production mode, you don't need to use those ports. you already got the proper application in case you enter to the main domain, it's looks like you just need to update the .htaccess file.

Comment: how to get rid of ports? and what should be updated or added in .htaccess?

Comment: @shushu304 I am using port 80 but still same issue Try Link: http:/3.16.214.113 and tried all above but same problem.
Please help!

Comment: i'm getting error for this address looks like it's not available, if you entering this url ... what you see? the main page of your application?